# CakePHP form selection as parameter

Tags: php, forms, cakephp, select

I have the following code in my **index.ctp** view to create a form:

```
<?php 
    echo $this->Form->create(false,array('url' => array('controller' => 'admins', 'action' => 'edit_gallery')));

    echo $this->Form->input('name', array('options' => $array,'empty' => 'Select a gallery'));

    echo $this->Form->end(__('Submit', true));
?>
```

Thi codes creates a dropdown list of items, each one with an associated number as value. 
In my **admins_controller** I have the **edit_gallery** action implemented exactly as it comes when you bake a project, only that I changed the typical **edit** to **edit_gallery**.

What I want is the following: the user selects one item from the list, then clicks 'Submit', and he's taken to the **edit_gallery.ctp** view, with a form to edit the information of that item in the database and update it. My problem is that, instead of doing this, what happens is that when the user clicks **Submit**, a new item is created in the database, and it doesn't even show the ctp view.

In general, my question would be: how can I get the selected option of the form in the landing page after the user clicks 'Submit'?

**Edit**
Ideally, what I would want is that, when the user clicks 'Submit', it would send a request like **admins/edit_gallery/x** where **x** would be the value associated to the selection made by the user, without sending any other data to the action. I don't know if that's possible.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The edit method that CakePHP bakes check by default if ***data*** is not null, in other words, if a form has been submitted, and then updates that record.

So, when you redirect to *edit_gallery* from a form, the ***data*** property is not null, therefore the reason for the new item creation in the database.

There are many ways to solve this. One of them is to remove that check from the *edit_gallery* method, create another method like *save_gallery*, and call that method from *edit_gallery.ctp*.

So the *edit_gallery.ctp* form would look something like:

```
<?php 
    echo $this->Form->create(false,array('url' => array('controller' => 'admins', 'action' => 'save_gallery')));

    (your form info)

    echo $this->Form->end(__('Submit', true));
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I'll check that out. However, just for curiosity, do you know if it's possible what I explain in my **Edit** part of my post?